# Error while signing APK using Android Studio-"Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'."

Tags: android

I am trying to "Generate Signed APK" using Android Studio, but I am getting an error saying:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

How do I fix this?

**Image Of Errors In Messages View:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps**

**1**. In build.gradle

aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }

**2**. Delete content inside C:\Users.gradle\caches

**3**. Restart Android Studio

Comment: Thank you so much I have been trying to solve this problem for months :)

Comment: Great @Aakash Keep Coding.